# Swift How to access information in nested structs?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, nested

I have a large nested struct data file with Topic and Subtopic information.

```
struct Topic{
    struct Topic1{
      let name = "Topic 1"
        let description = "Topic 1 description here."

        struct SubtopicUniqueName1 {
            let title = "Subtopic title here." 
            let subtopicDescription = "Some lorem ipsum description...."
            let subtopicContent = ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
        }

        struct SubtopicUniqueName2 {
            let title = "Subtopic title here." 
            let subtopicDescription = "Some lorem ipsum description...."
            let subtopicContent = ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
        }
    }

    struct Topic2{
        let name = "Topic 2"
        let description = "Topic 2 description here."
        struct SubtopicUniqueName3 {
            let title = "Subtopic title here." 
            let subtopicDescription = "Some lorem ipsum description...."
            let subtopicContent = ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get an array of all the "name" of Topic1, Topic2, ... and so on because I will have up to 14 topics in the end. It will not run when I try `let allTopics = [Topic.Topic1, Topic.Topic2]`

I wanted to get the information by doing something like

```
for i in allTopics{
   print(i().name)
}
```

Lastly because the Subtopics structs are nested even further, would I access their content in a similar fashion within a Topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing values and types. You only really have two types here: topics, and sub-topics. So let's make them:

```
struct Topic {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let subTopics: [SubTopic]
}

struct SubTopic {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let content: [String]
}
```

Everything else is just an instance of one of those two types:

```
let topics = [
    Topic(
        name: "Topic 1",
        description: "Topic 1 description here.",
        subTopics: [
            SubTopic(
                title: "Subtopic title here.",
                description: "Some lorem ipsum description...",
                content: ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
            ),
            SubTopic(
                title: "Subtopic title here.",
                description: "Some lorem ipsum description...",
                content: ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
            ),
        ]
    ),
    Topic(
        name: "Topic 2",
        description: "Topic 2 description here.",
        subTopics: [
            SubTopic(
                title: "Subtopic title here.",
                description: "Some lorem ipsum description...",
                content: ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
            ),
        ]
    ),
]
```

Since these are just regular arrays, you can iterate them easily:

```
for topic in topics {
    print("\(topic.name) - \(topic.description)")
    print()

    for subTopic in topic.subTopics {
        let content = subTopic.content.joined(separator: "\n\t")
        print("""
            \(subTopic.title) - \(subTopic.description)
            \(content)

        """)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Topic 1 - Topic 1 description here.

    Subtopic title here. - Some lorem ipsum description...
    First Sentence
    Second Sentence
    Hello

    Subtopic title here. - Some lorem ipsum description...
    First Sentence
    Second Sentence
    Hello

Topic 2 - Topic 2 description here.

    Subtopic title here. - Some lorem ipsum description...
    First Sentence
    Second Sentence
    Hello
```

Comment: Continuing from the comment in the other post: this is definitely a much better solution to the task I was trying to do. From here I can easily pass this data to my view controllers. Great analogy about the computer & the web pages, too, it helps me understand better. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: @geistmate Hey, did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes sir, it did. Thank you. Just marked as Answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

the type of allTopics is [Any] which hides a member of a specific class.

**Solution:**

Create a protocol with a property `name` and any other properties which you are interested and apply it to a structures which should have those properties then create a collection of objects which implement the protocol.
The collection can be iterated and properties of the protocol are accessible without casting.

```
let allTopics: [TopicName] = [Topic.Topic1(), Topic.Topic2()]
allTopics.forEach {
    print($0)
}

protocol TopicName {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct Topic{
    struct Topic1: TopicName {
      let name = "Topic 1"
        let description = "Topic 1 description here."

        struct SubtopicUniqueName1 {
            let title = "Subtopic title here."
            let subtopicDescription = "Some lorem ipsum description...."
            let subtopicContent = ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
        }

        struct SubtopicUniqueName2 {
            let title = "Subtopic title here."
            let subtopicDescription = "Some lorem ipsum description...."
            let subtopicContent = ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
        }
    }

    struct Topic2: TopicName {
        let name = "Topic 2"
        let description = "Topic 2 description here."
        struct SubtopicUniqueName3 {
            let title = "Subtopic title here."
            let subtopicDescription = "Some lorem ipsum description...."
            let subtopicContent = ["First Sentence", "Second Sentence", "Hello"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer to my problem. Would I need to create a new protocol if I want to access the information for all subtopics under one of the topics? I.e. Topic1, get array for [SubtopicUniqueName1, SubtopicUniqueName2] and use methods to get data.

Comment: So if I want to access "title" for each Subtopic, I would add var title: String { get } to the protocol, and then iterate through an appropriate array that I would have to create since it is deeper nested?

Comment: @geistmate yes, exactly.

Comment: This is a bandaid on a bullet hole. Sure you can unify all these different types under a protocol, but it doesn't answer the question of why there are so many types in the first place.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I definitely have to improve this later. Swift beginner here and I am storing a lot of text data within a swift file to pass into my multiple view controllers. It will be a mobile educational app. There are many topics, each with their own subtopics and their content. This is how I figured to do it with what I currently know. If you have a reference to better means, I will gladly love to read and learn.

Comment: @geistmate See my answer. Don't create new struct (types) just to store fixed sets of instance methods. You can't even access those values, without first making an instance (e.g. `Topic1()`, which is shorthand for `Topic1.init()`), which doesn't really even make sense, because there's no distinguishing features between all instances of `Topic1`, because they all have the same hard coded values. A marginal improvement would be using `static` values, so you could directly do `Topic1.name`, to access the `name` static property directly on `Topic1`, without the need for a useless instance

Comment: ...but that's not a good idea, either. Imagine buying a new computer everytime you wanted to open a different web page. That's senseless. You would use one computer, and access multiple pages. Similarly, you should make only a few types that make sense (`Topic`, `SubTopic`, though they seem identical), and create multiple distinct instances of those types, each with the values that you want.